# less - How to get matching line not be the top line on screen?

Tags: search, less, scrolling, pager

Very often happens that I do

```
$ man someprogram
```

to inspect the manual for some program. Often I also want to search for something in there, and I simply hit <kbd>/</kbd> and write whatever I want to search for.

Unfortunately, whatever the match is, it is brought to the top line of the screen, therefore most of the times I need to scroll up manually a few times to actually see some context for that matching line.

How can I set `less` such that it leaves some offset lines between the top line and the matching line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want the `-j` option. See under ["OPTIONS" in the man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html):

> `-jn` or `--jump-target=n`
>
> Specifies a line on the screen where the "target" line is to   be
> positioned.  The target line is the line specified by any   command to
> search for a pattern, jump to a line number, jump   to a file
> percentage or jump to a tag.
>
> The screen line may be   specified by a
> number: the top line on the screen is 1, the   next is 2, and so on.
> The number may be negative to specify a   line relative to the bottom
> of the screen: the bottom line on   the screen is -1, the second to
> the bottom is -2, and so on.
>
> Alternately, the screen line may be
> specified as a fraction of   the height of the screen, starting with a
> decimal point: .5 is   in the middle of the screen, .3 is three tenths
> down from the   first line, and so on.  If the line is specified as a
> fraction, the actual line number is recalculated if the   terminal
> window is resized, so that the target line remains at   the specified
> fraction of the screen height.
>
> If any form of   the -j option is
> used, repeated forward searches (invoked with   "n" or "N") begin at
> the line immediately after the target   line, and repeated backward
> searches begin at the target line,   unless changed by -a or -A.  For
> example, if "-j4" is used,   the target line is the fourth line on the
> screen, so forward   searches begin at the fifth line on the screen.
> However   nonrepeated searches (invoked with "/" or "?")  always begin
> at the start or end of the current screen respectively.

Note: you can configure the option using `lesskey`, use an environment variable like `LESS=-j5 man someprogram` or just type `-j5` while in less.

Comment: Perfect. Especially the fact that one can use `-j.5` for the middle of the screen.